# How to initialize a child class if parent class has abstract method?

Tags: python

I have a ABC in python:

```
class Parent(ABC):

   self.__init__(self, common_data):
      self.common_data = common_data
    
   @abstractmethod
   def only_child_class_implements_it(self) -> int:
      pass

   def common_method(self):
      result = self.only_child_class_implements_it()
      return process_results(result)
```

My child classes don't need to implement self.**init**

Now I have something like:

```
child_class = module_level_func_get_child_class(input)(common_data)
child_class.common_method
```

I get an expected type check error:`cannot instantiate Parent because it has abstract method`, and that's because `module_level_func_get_child_class` is annotated to return `Parent`:

```
def module_level_func_get_child_class(input: str) -> Parent:
   // Factory logic that returns one of the child classes
```

How can I gracefully avoid this error where I want to call the constructor on the `parent` but on an `child` class?

Comment: Are you getting a warning by a static type checker, or is that a runtime error when you actually try to instantiate the class?

Comment: `self.__init__` is surely a typo!?

Comment: As currently written. this question is very unclear. Is it about type hints or what? If your child classes implement abstract methods, you'll be able to instantiate them.

Comment: I think you would help us to help you if you provided more code. The module_level_func_get_child_class() function definition seems pretty important for not showing us

Comment: You definitely need to show more code, because simple attempt to reproduce does nor reveal any issues: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=2e4dc796fe7cb58e69c81b0b813b74b3

Comment: Maybe this should be a `Protocol` rather than (or in addition to) an `ABC`?

Comment: @deceze sorry, updated question. Yes its a type checking error

Comment: Now it's even more confusing... Please show implementation of that function and its call site too:/

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. The `class` statement that defines `Parent` wouldn't execute, as `self.__init__` would produce a `NameError`. There's no definition shown for the child class that purportedly defines `only_child_class_implements_it`. There's no definition given for `module_level_func_get_child_class`. `child_class.common_method` should be irrelevant, as `child_class` shouldn't be defined in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a `Protocol` for your type annotations.  You can combine this with an `ABC` that provides implementation of the common methods.  Here's an example (that typechecks fine with `mypy`):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Protocol, Type

def process_results(value: int) -> int:
    return 2 * value

class ParentProtocol(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, common_data: int): ...
    def only_child_class_implements_it(self) -> int: ...
    def common_method(self) -> int: ...

class Parent(ParentProtocol, ABC):

    def __init__(self, common_data: int):
        self.common_data = common_data
    
    @abstractmethod
    def only_child_class_implements_it(self) -> int: ...

    def common_method(self) -> int:
        result = self.only_child_class_implements_it()
        return process_results(result)

class Child(Parent):
    def only_child_class_implements_it(self) -> int:
        return self.common_data * 7

def get_child_class() -> Type[ParentProtocol]:
    return Child

print(get_child_class()(3).common_method())
```